# Since upgrading to Xcode 12, cannot add custom plist files to product targets

Tags: xcode, macos

Ever since I upgraded to Xcode 12, I cannot add custom plist files that I drag into Xcode to product targets. This is for a macOS command line terminal application. When I click on the plist file in the navigator and view it in the file inspector, the product is unchecked in the target membership window and I cannot check it (won't allow me); the product, however, is not greyed out. For command line terminal applications, is there an alternate way around this?

Comment: "add my project as a target to custom plist files" Sorry, can't make sense of those words; a _project_ cannot be a _target_. "the project is unchecked in the target membership window and I cannot check it" Okay, those words make sense, but a _project_ would never be a _target member_, so what sense is this even supposed to make?

Comment: @matt product, sorry, not project.

Comment: Okay, cool, but I still can't make sense of the phrase "add my product as a target to custom plist files". How can a _product_ be a _target_, and what does this have to do with plist files? Maybe you could show a screen shot of what you are wishing to do and explain the purpose of doing it?

Comment: @matt I edited it with clearer phrasing. What I meant to say is that I cannot add the custom plist file to any of the product targets.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But then what does this have to do with Xcode 12? Do you claim this was possible with Xcode 11?

Comment: @matt never had this issue with previous Xcode versions and it seems suspicious that it happened right after the upgrade. It may or may not be related but I thought it might be useful to mention.

Comment: Ok but I'm looking at Xcode 11 and the checkbox for target membership is not clickable there either. And that makes sense to me, because this is not a bundle. You can include files manually in the Copy Files build phase, but of course you must say where they should be copied _to_. I'll give that as an answer, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check and uncheck the checkbox in the Target Membership in the File inspector, because this is not a bundle — it's a command-line tool, not an application. But you can include a resource manually in the Copy Files build phase, though of course in that case you must specify where it is to be copied *to* at install time.

Comment: I do not see a build phases tab in the command line tool interface that I would normally see in an iOS application interface, for example. I assume it's somewhere in the build settings tab but I'm unsure where in there I must manually add resources?

Comment: I see it. You have to edit the target, not the project. The project has no build phases, obviously, but the target does.